# SQL query by enum literal

Tags: java, ignite

Is there a way to use string literal in WHERE clause of SQL query?

I'm running following test (Ignite 2.13.0) and it is failing with error:

```
package query;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static query.SQLQueryTest.Sex.F;
import static query.SQLQueryTest.Sex.M;

public class SQLQueryTest {
    class Person implements Serializable {
        private long id;
        private Sex sex;
        private String name;

        public Person(long id, Sex sex, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public enum Sex {
        M, F
    }

    @Test
    void queryByEnum() {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
        CacheConfiguration<Long, Person> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<Long, Person>();
        personCacheCfg.setName("Person");

        QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity(Long.class, Person.class)
                .addQueryField("id", Long.class.getName(), null)
                .addQueryField("sex", Sex.class.getName(), null)
                .addQueryField("name", String.class.getName(), null);

        personCacheCfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(queryEntity));

        IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = ignite.createCache(personCacheCfg);
        cache.put(1L, new Person(1, F, "Lena"));
        cache.put(2L, new Person(2, M, "Vova"));
        cache.put(3L, new Person(3, F, "Anya"));
        cache.put(4L, new Person(4, M, "Petya"));

        SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Person where sex='M'");
        assertEquals(2, cache.query(qry).getAll().size());
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Failed to parse query. Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "M"; SQL statement:
select * from Person where sex='M' [90003-197]
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "M"; SQL statement:
select * from Person where sex='M' [90003-197]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:859)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:432)
    at query.SQLQueryTest.queryByEnum(SQLQueryTest.java:55)
```

I appreciate that there is easy fix for that using setArgs method like below:

```
        SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Person where sex=?").setArgs(M);
```

but what I want is to use literal in sql query. Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aparently solution is to cast enum value to varchar.
So below resolves the issue:

```
SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Person where CAST(sex AS VARCHAR)='M'");
```